# Ubuntu 14.04 - Python 3.4 - pyenv: command Not Found

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to create a virtual environment for Python 3.4 on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 14.04.  I following the instructions for the venv module at:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv

I don't have a lot of Python 3.4 or Ubuntu experience.

When I type the command:

```
pyvenv testDir
```

I get back:

```
pyvenv: command not found
```

What is causing this?

Comment: possbile duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/578872/ubuntu-14-04-pyenv-command-not-found

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 uses Python 2 by default, and the `pyenv` command does not exist in Python 2 out of the box.

You can, however, use `virtualenv` for the same purpose. You just need to install it!

You should:

- Install Python 3 and virtualenv `apt-get install -y python3 python-virtualenv`
- Create a Python 3 virtualenv: `virtualenv -p $(which python3) testDir`
- Activate the virtual environment with `source testDir/bin/activate`

Comment: So, I shouldn't worry about using the newer venv module with the pyvenv command?

Comment: When I try:

virtualenv -p $(python3.4) testDir

it launches me into the python interpreter and I then see:

Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
The executable testDir (from --python=testDir) does not exist

Comment: @timbram The command has `$(which python3)`, not `$(python3)`.

Comment: Thanks!  That works!  Where did you find that command?  I don't see that anywhere in the virtualenv documenation.

Comment: @timbram This is a feature of your shell (not of `virtualenv`)  called [Command Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

Comment: Oh ok, so the -p tells it to expect you to define a python interpreter to use, and then you use the command substitution to, I guess define for it which one to use.  Thanks, I will have to look into it more! :)

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! It works without step 1.

Comment: I had to use `virtualenv --always-copy` to avoid a weird symlink issue, but otherwise, this worked.

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible to create virtualenv by python itself.
python3 -m venv myenv

see documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the package `python3.4-venv` (Linux Mint) or `python3-venv` (Ubuntu - I guess).

The advantages of `venv` over `virtualenv` are that (1) it's in vanilla Python3, (2) interpreter **does** retain tab-completion.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .bashrc file present in your home directory by adding below code and save the file:

```
# Load pyenv automatically by adding
# the following to ~/.bashrc:
export PATH="/home/'Enter systemname here'/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

After this you can now run the following command:

```
    exec $SHELL
```

Now pyenv works properly

Comment: Pls briefly explain what your changes do and why they will work

Comment: Defined environment to point to the path where pyenv repository is cloned and used exec command to update the path.