# How to install a python 3.6 environment using pyenv

Tags: python, python-venv

I have provisioned an instance of a GPU-backed VM to do machine learning research, but the default OS installed is Ubuntu 16.04 and the default Python version is 3.5. It seems that the package I want to use is only compatible with Python 3.6.

I am trying therefore to install Python 3.6, which from what I understand I should be able to do with pyenv. When I try to run this command, I am told:

```
Command 'pyenv' not found, did you mean:

  command 'p7env' from deb libnss3-tools
  command 'pyvenv' from deb python3-venv

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

So I install the `python3-venv` package. But still, running `pyenv virtualenv 3.6.1 my-virtual-env-3.6.1` gives me the same response as above, as though it was not installed at all.

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954984/ubuntu-14-04-python-3-4-pyenv-command-not-found

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/578872/ubuntu-14-04-pyenv-command-not-found