# Ubuntu 18.04 Command 'pyenv' not found, did you mean:

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, pyenv

So here is my Ubuntu version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I'm trying to run the following command: `pyenv install 3.6.2` but i get the error:

```
Command 'pyenv' not found, did you mean:
  command 'pyvenv' from deb python3-venv
  command 'p7env' from deb libnss3-tools
```

I've searched and this post ([Ubuntu 14.04 - Python 3.4 - pyenv: command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954984/ubuntu-14-04-python-3-4-pyenv-command-not-found)) states Ubuntu 14.04 and below use Python 2 be default so one has to use `virtualenv` instead, but why does my 18.04 Ubuntu not recognize the command?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

First see if you have the **curl** already installed in your machine using the command:

`$ curl --version`

If you don't have, install the curl using:

`$ sudo apt-get install curl`

After that install the pyenv using the command:

`$curl https://pyenv.run | bash`

And after installation update your **bashrc** adding the lines:

```
export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Finally Reload the **bashrc**:

`$ source ~/.bashrc`

I think will work fine after that. If you installed the pyenv before, look up at you bashrc to confirm if you added the lines above and reload the bashrc again.

Comment: I'm new to editing the .bashrc, do I just add those commands to the top of the file or does it have to go somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Every time will put something on the bashrc you should put at the bottom. Remenber to run the bash as root also ($ gedit ./bashrc), save the file and run the ($ source ~/.bashrc)

Comment: in my Ubuntu 18.04 I had to change the 3rd line added in ~/.bashrc for: eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init --path)"

Comment: These didn't work for me on 18.04. I have to use [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67779866/1786351) from this similar question.

Comment: These `export`/`eval` commands are not shown in the `pyenv-installer` repo installation instructions. Where did you come up with these steps?

Comment: Does anyone know why this doesn't persist after a new terminal session?