# pyenv no longer sets paths correctly when activating virtual environments

Tags: python, fish, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I've been using pyenv for almost two years with no problems on my system running RHEL 8.3 (Linux kernel 4.18) with Gnome 3.32.2 in X11 mode. I primarily use the fish shell but also occasionally bash, both worked fine with pyenv until now. However, after running `pyenv update` about 24 hours ago, using the `pyenv activate` command to activate one of my created virtual environments no longer sets the path to use what I've installed in that virtual environment.

When I start a terminal session, I see a new message saying:

```sh
WARNING: `pyenv init -` no longer sets PATH.
Run `pyenv init` to see the necessary changes to make to your configuration.
```

So I ran `pyenv init` which told me:

```
# Add pyenv executable to PATH by adding
# the following to ~/.profile:

set -Ux PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
set -Ux fish_user_paths $PYENV_ROOT/bin $fish_user_paths

# Load pyenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.config/fish/config.fish:

pyenv init - | source

# and the following to ~/.profile:

pyenv init --path | source

# If your ~/.profile sources ~/.config/fish/config.fish,
# the lines should be inserted before the part
# that does that.

# Make sure to restart your entire logon session
# for changes to ~/.profile to take effect.
```

I'm pretty sure I already have all of the above. Here's my `~/.profile`:

```
set -Ux PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
set -Ux fish_user_paths $PYENV_ROOT/bin $fish_user_paths
pyenv init --path | source
```

Here's my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
# Set default editor
set -gx EDITOR nano

# Set Junest path
set PATH /home/[username]/.local/share/junest/bin $PATH

# Set pyenv root directory
set PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv

# Add pyenv and local bin to $PATH
set PATH $PYENV_ROOT/bin /home/[username]/.local/bin $PATH

# Add pyenv init to shell to enable shims and autocompletion 
# Note the command `pyenv init` will tell you to add this line for fish
status --is-interactive; and source (pyenv init -|psub)

pyenv init - | source
```

My `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific environment
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging featur$
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions

# Load pyenv
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

A few more observations:

1. I discovered that even though I have `~/.profile`, it is never sourced/run when I log into my desktop environment.
2. Putting `set -Ux PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv` and `set -Ux fish_user_paths $PYENV_ROOT/bin $fish_user_paths` in `~/.profile` or `~/.config/fish/config.fish` doesn't make a difference.

In the end, even after activating a pyenv-created virtual environment, I still don't have access to what's in it.

How can I troubleshoot this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't really know anything about pyenv so maybe I'm off here, but I found this seemingly related [issue](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1906). Maybe it's helpful.

Answer (score 17):

OS: `ubuntu 18.04`

I updated `pyenv` by

```
pyenv update
```

and it start showing this warning

```
WARNING: `pyenv init -` no longer sets PATH.
Run `pyenv init` to see the necessary changes to make to your configuration.
```

and `pyenv` no longer sets the path correctly

### FIX

1. 

I have these lines in my `~/.bashrc` . So, **delete/comment** these lines if you have in `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="/home/yogi/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

2. 

Add these lines in `~/.profile` **before** sourcing `~/.bashrc`

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

3. 

Source profile

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: Also fixed me on MacOS

Comment: Worked for me just now on Ubuntu 20.04, thank you.

Comment: This worked for me too on WSL2! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

The message is wrong. ~/.profile is for posix-compatible shells, which fish is not, and so it won't read it. This should be reported as a bug in pyenv.

Now, you already have the code to add to $PATH in your config.fish, so it appears no further action from your end is necessary, the warning does not apply to you.

Your ~/.profile is fish-code, which is incompatible with shells that will read it and I suggest removing it.

---

If you didn't already have all the necessary bits:

Weirdly enough the actual *code* is fish-compatible (except for `pyenv init --path`, which prints posix code. I suggest just skipping it). Since it recommends using universal variables via `set -U`, and those persist, you'll just want to run the `set -U` once *interactively*:

```
set -Ux PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
set -Ux fish_user_paths $PYENV_ROOT/bin $fish_user_paths
```

You do **not** want to add these in config.fish. Fish persists universal variables and this one *adds* to $fish_user_paths, so it will add one component every time you open a fish, which will just end up leaving you with hundreds of elements in it and slow down fish.

Alternatively add $PYENV_ROOT/bin to $PATH yourself in config.fish, just like the $PATH additions you're already doing:

```
# Set pyenv root directory
set -gx PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
# (note that this must now come later because it uses $PYENV_ROOT)
set -gx PATH /home/[username]/.local/share/junest/bin $PYENV_ROOT/bin $PATH
```

(or use `fish_add_path`, shipped in fish 3.2 - `fish_add_path /home/[username]/.local/share/junest/bin $PYENV_ROOT/bin` - this will take care of not adding it multiple times)

Keep the `pyenv init - | source` (which ends up doing the same as `source (pyenv init -|psub)` without a useless temp file, so it's preferred)

Comment: Message is fixed upstream: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/pull/1916

Answer (score 6):

Just replace the line `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` from your `~/.bashrc` file to `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`.

Please refer this issue: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1906

Comment: To the point! https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#readme

Answer (score 5):

For Mac and fish, add this to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
set PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
set -x PATH $PYENV_ROOT/shims $PATH
set -x PATH $PYENV_ROOT/bin $PATH

if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    pyenv init - | source
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who have landed on this question and are using something other than fish, I also tried to follow the directions given by `pyenv -init` without success.  Like @jmunsch, I have Ubuntu 20.04 and bash.  However, it appears `~/.profile` is either not being read or something in my bash configuration is overwriting the relevant `~/.profile` settings before `pyenv -init` gets to run.  No idea what this may be, but before anyone asks:

1. Yes, the `~/.profile` changes were set before the line that sources `~/.bashrc`
2. No, I don't use `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`

Here's what I did instead, **ALL** in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PYENV_ROOT=$HOME/.pyenv
export PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
# <Other commands not relevant to pyenv - jump straight to evals if you like>
# .
# .
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

I haven't tested `pyenv` exhaustively, but the warning has gone away and it seems to be functioning OK.